# Solve THIS ODE $ (2x-y\sin(2x))dx = (\sin^2x-2y)dy $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The following problem is in Mathematical Methods in physical science CH8 miscellaneous problems
$$
(2x-y\sin(2x))dx = (\sin^2x-2y)dy
$$
it isnt an exact equation the only difference is $-$ sign
because it not an exact equation I tried to rearrange it to produce linear first order but it did not work
I dont know what to do
I assume there an integration factor for such problem to make it exact or methods

Also I tried to use Mathematica DSolve function to find a solution

```
DSolve[{y'[x] == (2 x - y[x] sin (2 x))/(sin^2 x - 2 y[x])}, y[x], x]
```

This what it produced

```
DSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of True in the first argument {True}.
DSolve[{True}, y[x], x]
```

thank you

Comment: Please provide more context; What methods did you have in mind for solving this ODE? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Recall we say a differential equation of type
$$N(x,y)dx+M(x,y)dy=0$$ is exact if $$\frac{\partial N}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}$$

So re-writing the above differential equation as
$$
(2x-y\sin(2x))dx - (\sin^2x-2y)dy
=0$$

we can see that $$\frac{\partial N}{\partial y}=-\sin(2x)=\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}$$
so it is in fact exact.

Answer (score 0):

Since $d[x^2+y^2-y\sin^2x]=(2x-y\sin2x)dx+(2y-\sin^2x)dy=0$, the solution is $x^2+y^2-y\sin^2x=c$.

Comment: but how did you find it did you guess the solution

Comment: @32threeone Since rearranging to get $dy/dx$ doesn't give an obviously easily solved equation, the next thing to try is to  write $df=f_xdx+f_ydy=0$ for some $f$. Since $(\sin^2x)_x=\sin2x$, it's not hard to work out the choice of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

$$(2x-y\sin(2x))dx = (\sin^2x-2y)dy$$
$$(2x-y\sin(2x))= (\sin^2x-2y)y'$$
$$2x+2yy'=y'\sin^2 x +y \sin (2x)$$
$$2x +(y^2)'=(y \sin^2 x)'$$
Integrate.